# Interface inside class

Tags: java, class, interface

What's the difference between using interface inside class, inside nested class and outside class.

As I was reading about the class [`DataStructure.java`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/DataStructure.java) in [Questions and Exercises: Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/QandE/nested-questions.html) at Oracle (pasting here fragment of the example):

```
public class DataStructure {
//some code
    interface DataStructureIterator extends java.util.Iterator<Integer> { } 

    // Inner class implements the DataStructureIterator interface,
    // which extends the Iterator<Integer> interface

    private class EvenIterator implements DataStructureIterator {
//rest code
```

1. So as the code about shows there is no any body in interface. Couldn't I just extends EvenIterator class with `java.util.Iterator<Integer>` instead of creating this interface and implements it?
2. Is there any other difference (aside from code readability) between declaring interference outside/inside class?
3. What will happen when the outer class gonna be extended by a interface. Will it impact in any way on nested class?

Just want to be sure about these things to know how to use them properly, thanks for your time.

Comment: No difference, `interface` is always implicitly `static` even if not declared as such. In this case the interface is used as a poor man's type alias.

Comment: Typically you only make inner classes for things that have some functional dependency on the parent class. For example, you have a clickable `View`, so you have an inner class listener named `View.OnClickListener`, otherwise an outer class is preferred

Comment: @cricket_007, in fact, even in this case it is preferred to use a separate interface because someone someday may wish to create an alternative `View` implementation. Or maybe reuse this interface in other clickable objects. Note that Java rarely (if ever) uses nested interfaces in the standard lib.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov `java.util.Map.Entry` is an example nested interface for the situation I mentioned

Comment: @cricket_007, yes, that's a good example. I was thinking more of various listeners (say, `ActionListener` is not a part of `Action`). Still, having a separate `MapEntry` interface wouldn't hurt at all.

Comment: @cricket_007, oh, and more importantly! `Map` is an interface as well. Here we are talking about interfaces inside classes. That's why I haven't thought of `Map`. Interfaces in classes are worse than in other interfaces because that way you're tying an abstract thing to a concrete thing with no reason.

Comment: @BoristheSpider what exactly means 'poor man's type alias'?

Comment: @Kubekk, they probably meant that `DataStructureIterator` is used as a synonym (that is, an alias) of `java.util.Iterator<Integer>`. Note that it isn't strictly an alias—both can't be used interchangeably. For example, you can't use a random iterator where a `DataStructureIterator` is expected. So I'd rather call it a poor man's typesafe alias.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov Yea I see that. I just don't know what exactly means 'poor man's type/typesave alias' <- that phrase with poor man. Could you tell me what does it mean?

Comment: @Kubekk, oh, that roughly means “cheap replacement for something” or “an alternative to be used when you don't have the real thing”. Like, if you're so poor that you can't afford real type aliases, you'll have to settle with a cheaper replacement. E. g. a wildcard is a poor man's regular expression. Or search-and-replace is a poor man's refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. So as the code about shows there is no any body in interface. Couldn't I just extends EvenIterator class with
>      java.util.Iterator instead of creating this interface and
>      implements it?

Yes, you could. But this way it may be more readable and extendable. Even if there are no members now, they may be added later.

> 2. Is there any other difference (aside from code readability) between declaring interference outside/inside class?

A nested interface is implicitly static, so the only effect is that a nested interface is a part of the enclosing class namespace-wise.

Because members of a class may be declared as `protected` or `private`, that applies to nested interfaces as well. It rarely makes sense to use `private` interfaces, though, because they can only be implemented in the same class, so why bother with interfaces in the first place? However, `protected` interfaces may be useful. For example, you may have an abstract factory method that is used by the subclasses to provide instances to the parent class. Here's a contrived example:

```
public abstract class Enclosing {

    protected interface JobHandler {
        void handle(Job job) throws JobException;
    }

    protected abstract JobHandler createJobHandler();

    // public methods omitted

    private void doTheJob(Job job) {
        createJobHandler().handle(job);
    }
}
```

If the interface is declared package-private, it might as well just be at the package level. The only reason you may want to cram it inside a class is because it's very tightly coupled to the class itself. Perhaps it's some sort of helper interface that is used strictly in unit testing that particular class.

If the interface is `public`, then it's usually a bad idea to make it nested. Because by doing that, you increase coupling between the interface and the enclosing class. And interfaces are one of the best ways to *reduce* coupling! So why waste their potential?

Suppose you have a `mylib-buttons` library that have a `Button` class. One day having a `Button.ClickListener` seems to be a nice idea. Then you want to reuse this interface in another class, and possibly even in another library. But you can't do it without introducing a (probably unnecessary) dependency on the library that contains the `Button` class. On the other hand, if it's a top-level interface, then you just extract the interfaces into another library, say, `mylib-core`, leaving the messy buttons alone in the `mylib-buttons`.

Nested interfaces inside *interfaces* is a bit different story. They can be a part of the same design and intended to be used together. @cricket_007 in one of the comments gives a good example of that: `Map.Entry`.

> 3. What will happen when the outer class gonna be extended by a interface. Will it impact in any way on nested class?

This is not exactly clear. How can a class be extended by an interface? Nevertheless, whatever you meant here, you can probably answer it yourself if you consider the aforementioned fact: the nested interface is just a part of the class' namespace scope, and that's it. There are no other impacts whatsoever.

Comment: I meant implement. Like we've got outer class with implemented interface and if there will be any impact on the inner class, but I figured out that it won't (am I right? ). Thanks for the answer, it cleared my mind a bit.

Comment: @Kubekk, if some other class implements your nested interface (assuming it's not private)? Right, your inner class won't notice that. They would be just separate implementations of the same interface.