# What is the purpose of interface inside a Java class?

Tags: java, android, interface

In the sample code below, I have an `interface` inside class so that I'm using the methods of interface. But i don't see any effect with/without interface methods. Can someone help me what is the purpose of adding including them?

```
public class Controller {

    FlowerCallBackReceiver mListener;

    @Override
    public void success(String s, Response response) {
        try { 
            mListener.onFetchProgress(flower);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            mListener.onFetchFailed();
        }
        mListener.onFetchComplete();
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        mListener.onFetchComplete();
    }

    public interface FlowerCallBackReceiver {
        void onFetchProgress(Flower flower);
        void onFetchComplete();
        void onFetchFailed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clean up your code? You have a dangling catch with no try, a random `});` floating on its own etc.

Comment: Please compile the code that you plan to post. It should either compile clean, or raise the exact error you expect.

Comment: @Michael .My intention was to raise question regarding purpose of inner interface inside class so that i added edited  code to make it short. There might be some piece of code missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *nested interface* declaration is just a simple organizational technique. It won't change the standard Java `interface` semantics at all.

For instance, developers use it to clean up the top level package namespace. It's a matter a style, one may say.

Some quick **Java SE** examples:

- [`interface Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html)
- [`interface Map.Entry<K,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)
- [`interface Policy.Parameters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Policy.Parameters.html)
- [`interface DirectoryStream.Filter<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.Filter.html)
- [`interface ServiceRegistry.Filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/ServiceRegistry.Filter.html)
- etc

Comment: You may also want to have a look at these two other SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648642/why-should-we-declare-an-interface-inside-a-class and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530066/interface-inside-class

Comment: @GMax Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

There is no obvious reason to have that interface there, based on the code you have shown.

One might typically nest an interface inside a class if implementations of that class are to be used in the body of the rest of the class, for example if `Controller` had a method like:

```
void doSomething(FlowerCallBackReceiver callback) {
  // ...
}
```

But this interface isn't used here, so it's not apparent why it would be here.